# How to pass a class_name into a function to use in Sqlalchemy Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to a build a User-class function with an SQLAlchemy query inside that allows me to count the User-records on different tables (based on his id). To avoid multiple function codings, I tried to define a generic function where I  receive the db.modell class as a parameter from a Jinja2 call like:

```
{{ current_user.count('Customer') }}
```

or

```
{{ current_user.count('Player') }}
```

But I end up in errors that Python does not interpret the given class_name parameter as a real Class. He complains that class_name doesn't have a function id.
Of course I could specify specific User Functions with a specific query for each class but I tried to avoid those duplicate codings.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

```
class User(db.Model): 
  __tablename__='user'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


  def count(self, class_name): 
        s = db.session()
        count = s.query(class_name).filter(class_name.id == self.id).count()
        return count

class Player(db.Model):
   __tablename__='player'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Customer(db.Model):
   __tablename__='Customer'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Why not just pass the class itself? Naturally `class_name` does not have an attribute named `id`, because you have passed string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to pass the class itself to the function like this:

```
 def count(self, class_): 
    s = db.session()
    count = s.query(class_).filter(class_.id == self.id).count()
    return count
```

But if you have to pass a class name for some reason, you can do something like this:

```
 def count(self, class_name):
    class_ = {
        'player':Player,
        'customer':Customer,
    }[class_name.lower()]

    s = db.session()
    count = s.query(class_).filter(class_.id == self.id).count()
    return count
```

it is not very different but you can do this.

There is also another way, but I don't recommend this:

```
 def count(self, class_name):
    class_ = globals()[class_name]

    s = db.session()
    count = s.query(class_).filter(class_.id == self.id).count()
    return count
```

this way will just work if everything exists in `global` scope.
read about `globals` [Here](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/globals/)

note that:

> 1. Careful to not use `class` as a name of a variable, `class` is predefined. use something else like `class_`
> 2. It will raise `key error`if you pass a wrong class name in second way. you can handle it with `try` and `except`.

Comment: I didnt get the first proposal up and running to pass the class itself. I tried:
 {{ current_user.count(class ='Player') }} but it didnt work.

I believe it because in my template, the class is not known at all ?!

Comment: @MichaelHuhn you should remove `'`s. like this `{{ current_user.count(Player) }}`